# Is UIFont thread safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, thread-safety

Anybody can confirm whether `UIFont` (of Cocoa-Touch/iOS) is thread safe? That is, is it safe to use from within threads that are outside the main thread but the instance is not shared among threads?

The problem is that I'm doing that and I've been getting random crashes in `[NSString sizeWithFont:]` and beginning to think perhaps I shouldn't use `UIFont` from outside the main run loop?

Moreover [Apple's documentation on `UIFont`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) makes me doubtful if it can be used from other threads.

> You do not create UIFont objects using the alloc and init methods. Instead, you use class methods of UIFont to look up and retrieve the desired font object.

The above blurb sounds like `UIFont` has an instance cache stored somewhere and thus it may not be a good idea to use `UIFont` objects from outside the main thread since an instance may inadvertently be used by multiple threads and can cause problems. Heck, the `UIFont`'s *instance cache* could even be a source of thread contention.

Can anybody shed some light (with attributable links/evidences) on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you also accessing/modifying any UI elements (labels, textfields...) in this separate thread?

Comment: No, only used it to measure the size of some strings in the background. Been getting random crashes, not sure why. Anyway I've replaced that implementation with an equivalent made out of NSAttributedString / CTFont and there haven't been any crashes in that area in the past day.

Comment: Interesting news. This sounds like a workaround :) Hope you pull it off.

Answer (score 2):

rokjarc is right. If you want to change font of UI elements for example **font** property of the **UILabel** object, you should do it in the **main thread**.

But if you want to create UIFont instance in the separate thread, you are free to do it. The Apple documentation says the UIFont offers only static methods to you.